# Integration and ODE

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I integrate this?
$$y'=1+\frac{y}{x}$$
I just don't know how to start.

I think I gotta to try some variable changing, but I don't think I'm gonna so far with this.

Comment: Try setting $z(x)=y/x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** $$xy'-y=x$$
$$\frac{xy'-y}{x^2}=\frac{1}{x}$$
$$\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)'=\frac{1}{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
With a scaling $\quad\ds{y = \alpha\tilde{y}\,,\quad x\equiv \beta\tilde{x}}\quad$ the equation is reduced to:
\begin{align}
\totald{\tilde{y}}{\tilde{x}}&={\beta \over \alpha} + {y \over x}
\end{align}

> The equation is invariant when
>   $\quad\ds{\beta = \alpha\ \imp\ {x \over \tilde{x}} = {y \over \tilde{y}}\quad\imp\
> {\tilde{y} \over \tilde{x}} = {y \over x}}$ which suggest the change of variables $\ds{{y \over x} \equiv u\ \imp\ y = ux}$:

$$
u'x + u = 1 + u\quad\imp\quad u' = {1 \over x}\quad\imp\quad u = \ln\pars{x} + A
$$

> $$\color{#66f}{\large%
> {\rm y}\pars{x} = Ax + x\ln\pars{x}}\,,\qquad A\ \mbox{is a constant.}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

Your DEQ is inariant to the Lie stretching group $x'=\lambda x$, $y'=\lambda y$ and stabilizers for this group are $\mu=\frac{y}{x}$ and $\nu=y'$.  Since $$  x\frac{d\mu}{dx}=\nu-\mu$$ and in stabilizer form your DEQ is $$\nu=1+\mu$$ then $$x\frac{d\mu}{dx}=1$$ $$\mu=lnx+lnC=ln(Cx)$$  Substituting for $\mu$ yields the answer $$y=xln(Cx)$$